# Get the last ID after INSERT the PostgreSQL database with PgBouncer

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, pgbouncer, codeigniter

Previously we used PostgreSQL 9 with PgBouncer in session mode, and with that was able to easily create a new record and get the last ID with `pg_get_serial_sequence` and `CURRVAL`.

```
INSERT INTO "table" ("column") VALUES ('ABC');
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('table', 'tableid') AS seq;
SELECT CURRVAL('public.table_tableid_seq') AS ins_id;
```

But the use of the Session mode of PgBouncer proved to be extremely problematic for us, with several operations per second, the Pool easily reached the capacity of connections, so we switched to PostgreSQL 12 with PgBouncer in Transaction mode.

One problem that has begun to occur with this mode is that using operations that require being in the same session does not work, not allowing to use CURRVAL.

What is the best alternative to continue working in Transaction mode and get the ID after INSERT, without the risk of returning the ID generated by the same operation by another user?

An important detail is that we use a PHP Framework that does not allow  to add an `INSERT ... RETURNING` for each operation.

Comment: Why not use `insert ... returning id`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name CodeIgniter does not support `insert ... returning id`;

Comment: Ah, the joys of obfuscation layers. If you can't guarantee that everything is run on the same session, then I guess you are out of luck or need to change the pooling configuration of pgBouncer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm thinking of two options: 1 - Search for everything that requires a session and adapt to something without a session, 2 - Or change the mode to session on PgBouncer, which has caused several problems in the last days.

Comment: I am surprised that you can't guarantee a single transaction to run on the same connection - how is it possible to manage transactions at all in that context? I would have assumed that pgBouncer handles that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there any documentation that lists all functions that require the use of a session to function?
I searched but found nothing about it.

Comment: If the three commands shown were all in the same transaction, it shouldn't be a problem.  And if they aren't, that is pretty strange--i would think they should be for other reasons already.

Answer (score -1):

PostgreSQL creates a sequence by default per table. e.g actor_id_seq for the actor table on the column id.

So, this will return the last inserted id value:

```sql
select currval('actor_id_seq'::regclass)
```

The sequence generator operation is not transaction-safe. It means that if two concurrent database connections attempt to get the next value from a sequence, each client will get a different value. If one client rolls back the transaction, the sequence number of that client will be unused, creating a gap in the sequence.

Comment: Are you sure a client could get the last id of a different client ? i.e two clients would get the same id.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not sure how I read over that piece yesterday. I removed my incorrect comments.

Comment: I imagine if two clients triggered the sequence and a third client regretted, a gap in the sequence will occur.  A client requires the id to assign it to his row and build on that value.  The problem arises if two clients get the same sequence value, consequently if they are building invoice items, everyone will see suddenly the items of the other client in his invoice ( the common sequence value ).  I imagine the chance of this occurring is very rare because postgreSQL uses processes and not threads as the case in MySQL.

Comment: "*The problem arises if two clients get the same sequence value*" - this will never happen.

Comment: In scenarios where inserts occur offline and later synchronization with the centralized database occurs, the id idea is superseded by  using GUID where each row will be identified by a global unique identifier which is usually a 16 character string of random alphabet. GUID is known to be unique and almost zero chance of two GUIDS to be duplicate.